# regexp_matches returns NULL inside plpgsql function

Tags: regex, postgresql, pattern-matching, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1

Given a filename of:

xxxx/2013-02/csv/Sales_1302040000-1302050000.zip

Can someone explain why regexp_matches returns null in this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_import_batch_date(filename text) 
RETURNS DATE AS
$BODY$    
DECLARE
    matches text[];
    result date;
BEGIN

    matches := regexp_matches(filename, E'Sales_(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})');    
    IF matches IS NOT NULL THEN
        result := format('%s-%s-%s', 2000 + matches[1]::int, matches[2], matches[3])::DATE;
        RETURN result;
    END IF;

    RAISE WARNING 'Unable to determine batch date from %', filename;

    RETURN NULL;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

yet, works in the following anonymous function:

```
DO language plpgsql $$
DECLARE
    filename text := 'xxxx/2013-02/csv/Sales_1302040000-1302050000.zip';
    matches text[];
    result date;
BEGIN

    matches := regexp_matches(filename, E'Sales_(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})');    
    IF matches IS NOT NULL THEN
        result := format('%s-%s-%s', 2000 + matches[1]::int, matches[2], matches[3])::DATE;
        raise notice '%', result;
    END IF;

END;
$$;
```

And the regexp_matches seems to work correctly in this query, but again, the function fails and returns null

```
SELECT
    regexp_matches('xxxx/2013-02/csv/Sales_1302040000-1302050000.zip', E'Sales_(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})'),
    get_import_batch_date('xxxx/2013-02/csv/Sales_1302040000-1302050000.zip');
```

Is there a bug in my code that I'm just not seeing (very possible and the most common answer)  Or is there something I'm failing to do here?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1.6

Just a final note: given this filename, I want the function to return a date value of 2013-02-04

Answer (score 2):

#### Update:

The problem turned out to be a confusion over pgScript in pgAdmin. @David pressed F6 in the query tool of pgAdmin to run pgScript instead of **F5** for running an SQL script. See the [comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720394/regexp-matches-returns-null-inside-plpgsql-function/14743261#comment20631435_14743261).
The function itself is fine.

#### Simplified function

I can't reproduce your error (tested on Postgres 9.1.6, didn't return `NULL`), but I *can* offer you a much simpler version of your function that probably won't fail:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_import_batch_date(filename text, OUT result date)
  AS
$func$    
BEGIN
   result := ('20' || substring(filename, E'Sales_(\\d{6})'))::date;

   IF result IS NULL THEN
      RAISE WARNING 'Unable to determine batch date from %', filename;
   END IF;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

- Use an `OUT` parameter to simplify things.
- No need for the rather complex `regexp_matches()` expression and the array conversion it entails.
  A simple `substring()` call does the job. Prepend `20` and you convert to `date` tight away. The format matches ISO 8601 date format which is valid in *any* locale. Your original version relies on that as well, just with added hyphens (`-`), which are optional.

  ```
   `'20130204'::date` works just as well as `'2013-02-04'::date`
  ```

- No `RETURN` needed, the value of the `OUT` parameter `result` is returned automatically.

Comment: Thanks Erwin; Your answers are always great.  But, probably a stupid question here.  How can I use this function if I want to set a field value in an update statement?

Comment: @DavidS: Like `UPDATE tbl SET date_col = get_import_batch_date('mystring...')
WHERE tbl_id = ?` ..?

Comment: Oh. I see.  I feel dumb now.  I was thinking of it like how I did out params in Pascal (many years ago) and I needed a variable to pass it.  BUT, in either case, it doesn't work for me.  I have no idea why.  I cut and pasted the code exactly.  Maybe it's time to watch a movie.

Comment: BTW, thanks for educating me on ISO 8601.  I thought it had to be in the format of "YYYY-MM-DD".  Definitely learned something there.

Comment: @DavidS: Don't feel dumb, this is a Q&A site. And my new version doesn't work for you, either?

Comment: No; it doesn't work either.  I changed the name of the function just to make sure that I was calling it, and it returns null.  But, one thing that I did discover is that it doesn't appear that even the concatenation of "20" is needed.  It seems that '130204'::date will work and return the '2012-02-04'.  So, if that's the case then I can just pretty much do it in one call to a standard function and do a type cast and be done.  Which does work.

Comment: @DavidS: Very strange, I have no explanation for that. (`2012` is a typo, I'm sure.) Also, I am not sure whether the abridged format '130204' conforms to ISO 8601 or might depend on your locale setting. Better double check ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24064/discussion-between-david-s-and-erwin-brandstetter)

Comment: I finally figured it out.  See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Works here too: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d084b/1

Are you sure that was exactly the filename passed into get_import_batch_date?

Comment: Yes; I'm pretty sure.  I copied and pasted it, and triple checked it.  Even got a cup of coffee to take my eyes off it for a while.  Does it work if you create the function with the code above?

Comment: WOW!  Yep; it works for you on sqlfiddle.  But, I cut and pasted that code and it does not work for me.  What the $%#@?  It seems like it has to be something that I'm doing.  Gave you and upvote because of the work you did. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok!  I finally figured it out.  I'm not sure WHY this happens, or what is going on, but I can at least fix it.  The answer I'm posting here is actually based on Erwin's answer.  His code (as usual) is way better than mine, but this works if anyone else ever has this EXTREMELY frustrating problem in the future.

Basically, I was playing around with it again tonight and it finally caught my eye what was going on.  If I take this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_import_batch_date(in filename text, out result date) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
   result := substring(filename, E'Sales_(\\d{6})')::date;
   IF result IS NULL THEN
      RAISE WARNING 'Unable to determine batch date from %', filename;
   END IF;   
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE
  COST 100;
```

...and hit F6 to "run script", you get the following message back:

```
[QUERY    ] CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_import_batch_date(in filename text, out result date) AS
            $BODY$
            DECLARE
            BEGIN
               result := substring(filename, E'Sales_(\d{6})')::date;
               IF result IS NULL THEN
                  RAISE WARNING 'Unable to determine batch date from %', filename;
               END IF;   
            END
            $BODY$
              LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE
              COST 100
```

Can you spot the critical issue?  I couldn't last night, but did tonight.  It is stripping out one of the "\" on the substring function.

This will cause the match to fail and NULL to be returned.

If you hit F5 or click the "Run" button the function, then it works fine.  (which is probably what people were doing or maybe what SQLFiddle is doing (total guess here).

To get F6 to work for me, I had to change the line to:

```
   result := substring(filename, E'Sales_(\\\d{6})')::date;
```

So, that's what works for me.  This feels like a bug somewhere.  But, I don't know where.  Maybe @Erwin can shed some light on this.

Comment: The explanation is rather simple. Prepare your forehead to be slapped. :) In `pgAdmin` (which you never mentioned!!) F6 is the keyboard shortcut to execute **`pgScript`**, which uses it's own syntax rules as a meta language. Check out: http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.16/pgscript.html#pgscript

Comment: Yeah; really weird.  I didn't mention it because I never thought it would make a difference.  Now I know better. :) It was about to drive me crazy last night.  I couldn't figure out why everyone else was working.  I bet I cut & pasted your solution 3 or 4 times.

Comment: Just remember to press **`F5`** or hit the plain green arrow button in the SQL editor of pgAdmin to execute SQL commands. :) Or select some code and hit `F5` to exeucte only the highlighted part.

Comment: But, what about when you need to drop the function because the signature has changed?  I always have a "drop" when I'm working on a function. Or you need change the owner?  I just have a script to do this and hit F6. I didn't know it could parse differently.  I will say this, there might be an explanation for it, but this still feels really wrong.  That a function can be created (and return completely different results) based on how it was executed.  I get it, but it still feels really bad.

Comment: Slow down .. you are mixing at least 4 different things here. 1.) Owner is irrelevant. 2.) If the *function signature* doesn't change, you can update a function with `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ...`, else you have to drop and re-create it 3.) PostgreSQL allows [**function overloading**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-overload.html). 4.) None of this has *anything* to do with pgScript, which is a feature of pgAdmin (I hardly ever use.)

Comment: You lost me. Nothing should "break" if you run the reverse-engineered SQL-DDL scripts pgAdmin provides. There's just no point in re-running the `CREATE` script unless you change something. None of this has anything to do with your confusion over pgScript, which is an optional feature of pgAdmin, which you probably don't need at all. You might want to read up on [the manual of pgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.16/index.html).

Comment: True. I was just giving an example. And actually, if you look at the functions declaration in pgAdminIII, then it includes a drop (that is commented out) and then a create or replace followed by a ";" then a alter statement to make sure the owner is correct if you edit it. If you copy that text in to a query window, it seems to at least imply that you can run it as a script (that doesn't seem like a crazy assumption, but maybe it is). If you do, for this function above, you will break it and it will not return the correct results. That doesn't feel really bad?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24090/discussion-between-david-s-and-erwin-brandstetter)

Comment: Ok; I get it now.  Just always use F5. :D Thanks for your help!